# How to combine two files by shifting the value of the row file to its corresponding value in the column file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a two files, the first has one row while the second with one column 
I would like to  combine the two files  by shifting each value in the row file to the same value in the column file, then replace each empty cell before each value with x value and after it with y value.
 briefly, I would like those input files

```
row file
6  8  2  3  7  6  ...     

column file
1
2
3 
4  
5   
6
7
8  
.
.
```

after combination, the results should be as the following

```
output file
1   x  x  x  x  x  x  ....     
2   x  x  2  x  x  x  
3   x  x  y  3  x  x   
4   x  x  y  y  x  x  
5   x  x  y  y  x  x  
6   6  x  y  y  x  6  
7   y  x  y  y  7  y   
8   y  8  y  y  y  y  
9   y  y  y  y  y  y   
....   
....
```

Comment: I am trying to get the sum of each row of the final  output file with ignoring the first column values; actually, I will do further step before the summation, I will replace the shifted values  (the row file values) with x value

Comment: so, add your script to question, highlighting what is going wrong

Comment: and if you are using bash, check out http://www.shellcheck.net/ to get past common typos and potential drawbacks in your code... http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide if you want a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load one file in memory, and then handle the other one based on the values in memory.

Don't cheat... try it yourself first. Even if you try a bit that doesn't work, and ask about your code then. You will learn nothing if you don't try it yourself.

Here... I'll get you started. Here's how you make an array in bash:

```
# with while read
array=()
while read line; do 
    array+=("$line")
done < somefile

# the other way... sometimes necessary
IFS=$'\n\t ' # example IFS... in this case I am setting the normal default. For data that includes spaces, you exclude space here. If your data contains all 3, you have to use while read.
array=()
for line in $(cat somefile); do 
    array+=("$line")
done

# and here's looping over it
for n in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$n"
done
```

I can't figure out the syntax for a multi-line "spoiler"... so here's a 1 line script that will print the answer (in bash):

> base64 -d <<<"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"